# Casting DbSet<Entity> to its DbSet<IEntity> without pulling all entities to memory

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My Problem is that the system I am working with expects Data as `IQuearable<IEntity>` and entityframework gives me data as `IQueryable<Entity>`

This is from an interface I need to implement:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetData<T>() where T : class, IData {}
```

I have a DbSet created as context.Set(MyEntityType), where MyEntityType is typeof(Entity).

I have been trying a few things by now and not sure how I will get around this. (its all auto generated code from codedom, but made a test below to see that it can work, but havent got things working)

I made a wrapper for testing and the problem is here `LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types` If I can make this work I can make my other parts work also.

```
public class DbSetWrapper<C1Data,Entity>
    where C1Data : IData 
    where Entity: class
{

    public DbSetWrapper(C1AzureStoreRPContext context)
    {
        Data = context.Set<Entity>().Cast<C1Data>();
    }
    public IQueryable<C1Data> Data { get; private set; }
}

public class C1AzureStoreRPContext : DbContext
{
    static C1AzureStoreRPContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<C1AzureStoreRPContext>(null);
    }
    // Methods
    public C1AzureStoreRPContext(string connectionstring)
        : base(connectionstring)
    {

    }

    // Properties

    public DbSet<AzureStoreSubscriptionWrapper> AzureStoreSubscriptions { get; set; }
}
 public interface IAzureStoreSubscription : IData, IEntityFrameworkProvided {}
 public class AzureStoreSubscriptionWrapper : AzureStoreSubscription, IAzureStoreSubscription { }

 using (var c1 = new C1AzureStoreRPContext("opencms-sql-connection"))
 {
    var wrap = new DbSetWrapper<IAzureStoreSubscription, AzureStoreSubscriptionWrapper>(c1);
    Log.LogInformation("EF", string.Format("hello {0}", wrap.Data.ToList().Count));
 }
```

I don't want to pull all the data to memory and do the cast their, is there no other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IQueryable<T>` is covariant so instead of attempting to cast the `DbSet<SubType>` to `DbSet<SuperType>`, simply assign:

```
Data = context.Set<Entity>(); // .AsQueryable() not needed but does make it more readable
```

This, of course, depends on `Entity` implementing `C1Data`, which is not guaranteed based on your generic class definition (which is not good).  To fix this, change your type constraint for `Entity` as follows:

```
where Entity: C1Data
```

Comment: Will this also work if C1Data is an interface and not an actual implementation?

Comment: seems that I got things working. I was possitive that I had tried similar stuff with no success. Things are workign, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code that I ended up using in my application was:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetData<T>() where T : class, IData
{
    var factory = EntityFrameworkConfiguration.TypeFactory[typeof(T)];
    var context = factory.Item2();
    ThreadDataManager.GetCurrentNotNull().OnDispose += () =>
    {             
        context.Dispose();
    };

    var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod("Set", new Type[0]).MakeGenericMethod(factory.Item1);
    IQueryable<T> genericItem = (IQueryable < T >)method.Invoke(context, new object[0]);
    return genericItem;
}
```

And a note, the ThreadDataManager thing is a build in part of the system that I am integrating into.